# What's the difference between these 2 solidity interfaces methods?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I've been following a new journey into solidity for about a month now, so far so good, however with the Interface I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between these 2 methods of implementing Interfaces.

I can clearly notice how useful the Interface is in the 2nd method, but not in the 1st method.

Method 1:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface ICounter {

    function count() external view returns (uint256);
    function addToCount() external;
}

contract myInterface is ICounter {

    uint256 counter = 0;

    function count() external view override returns (uint256) {
        return counter;
    }

    function addToCount() override external {
        counter++ ;
    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract myContract {
    uint256 count =0;

    function increment() external {
    count++ ;
    }
}
```

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface ICounter {

    function count() external view returns (uint256);
    function increment() external;
}

contract myInterface {

    function incrementCount(address _counter) external {
        ICounter(_counter).increment();
    }

    function getCount(address _counter) external view returns (uint256) {
        return ICounter(_counter).count();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces in Solidity are mostly used for interacting with contracts deployed on other address, as you show in the **Method 2**.

Example of storing the pointer to another contract (assuming that it implements the interface) in a variable:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface ICounter {
    function increment() external;
}

contract MyContract {
    ICounter counter;

    constructor(address _counter) {
        counter = ICounter(_counter);
    }

    function incrementCount() external {
        counter.increment();
    }
}
```

---

In the **Method 1**, your code uses the `is` keyword for inheritance, which could be described as **"`myInterface` is child of `ICounter`"**.

But there's no way to explicitly state implementation of an interface - that **"`myInterface` implements `ICounter`"**. As you can see, you need to use the `override` modifier on the `addToCount()` function to state that you're **overriding** the parent function - which doesn't suggest implementing an interface at all.

I wouldn't consider the Method 2 a bad practice, as it can help you remember to implement all intended functions - otherwise the contract is treated as `abstract` and cannot be deployed. But for me personally, it's the less preferred method because there's no way to state an implementation instead of an inheritance (at least not in the current Solidity version 0.8).

*Note: I'm aware that for example OpenZeppelin [uses](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.4.2/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L35) the Method 1 of "inheriting from an interface". I just don't agree with their approach.. :)*

Comment: Regarding Method 1. Exactly why I kept digging for few days as the instructos course I've been following since the beginning used that method which I didn't find convenient. It's like using an interface but as an inherited contract, and as you mentionned it's we have to use Override and the only reason why Virtual is not implemented is that it is Virtual by default within the interface.

Comment: Now regarding Method2, and keeping in mind all the remarks you giving, is there any better approch in your opinion? I've seen another Method where the instructor used the interface within Contract1 and then used Import in the extensiated contract

Comment: @TheRealDude Using an `import` doesn't have any effect on the final bytecode or its gas usage, but it's a good way to separate the code into multiple files for easier readability... You can also create a variable with type of the interface, so that it's easier to access from multiple functions without having to always provide the external contract address. I edited my answer showing an example.

Comment: Hedja Thank you so much, so far this is the best approch I have seen. I saw a similar approch where he casted the address 1st and then he casted it into an Interface type, used Import, but I can't figure out why he used the Interface within the inherited from Contract and not the opposite. Any clue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70912706/figuring-out-a-solidity-interface-issue